# Magento Full Page Cache and Theme

Tags: magento, caching, themes

I am using magento full page cache, EE 1.11.2.  For some reason my secondary mobile theme is displaying on some of my catalog pages. e.g. two out of 6.  This only happens with FPC on.  It is reoccurring and happens on the same pages.  The cache can be valid or invalid.  I have not found any information on a topic similar to this.  Any ideas or suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: What are the URLs for your mobile and "normal" pages ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  They are the same urls. I looked into it deeper and the top nav has been customized and it looks like this is causing the problems.

Comment: I can't say if it's due to custom nav as problem is not described in details. What i can say is that in case of same URLs you can have this issue as FPC build cache basing upon specific URL.